# convert dateformat in awk, line contains 2 dates and one ip

Tags: bash, shell, awk

i have the following line:

```
192.168.1.200§Feb 24 10:22:14 2014 GMT§Aug 24 10:22:14 2014 GMT
```

and I want to convert it into this line with awk (or something else):

```
2014-02-24 2014-02-24 192.168.1.200
```

I was able to convert ONE Date with awk, using this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="§"} {cmd1="date \"+%Y-%m-%d\" -d \""$2"\""; cmd1 | getline var;  print var}'
```

but I don't know how to convert the row in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="§"
}

{
    cmd1="date \"+%Y-%m-%d\" -d \""$2"\""
    cmd1 | getline var1
    cmd2="date \"+%Y-%m-%d\" -d \""$3"\""
    cmd2 | getline var2
    print var1, var2, $1
}
```

Usage:

```
$ cat in.txt
192.168.1.200§Feb 24 10:22:14 2014 GMT§Aug 24 10:22:14 2014 GMT
$  awk -f conv.awk < in.txt
2014-02-24 2014-08-24 192.168.1.200
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with `awk`:

```
awk -v FS="§" '
BEGIN {
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", month, / /)
    for (i=1; i<=12; i++) { mm[month[i]] = sprintf("%02d",i) }
}
{
    split($2, d1, /[ :]/);
    split($3, d2, /[ :]/); 
    print d1[6]"-"mm[d1[1]]"-"d1[2], d2[6]"-"mm[d2[1]]"-"d2[2], $1
}' file
2014-02-24 2014-08-24 192.168.1.200
```

- You create your lookup table in `BEGIN` statement for all months.
- Split the 2nd and 3rd field on `space` and `:` in to an array.
- Format and print as desired.

Comment: Yup, this is how to do it... +1.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton .. means a lot getting an upvote from the master himself! `:)`